# Intercepting calls to properties

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to intercept all calls to properties on a Groovy class. Since this did not work as expected, I created the following example:

```
class TestClass {
    def getProperty(String key) {
        println "getting property: " + key
    }

    def invokeMethod(String method, args) {
        println "invoking method: " + method
    }

    def getFoo() {
        return 1
    }
}
tc.foo      // 1
tc.getFoo() // 2
```

1) does the right thing, that is getProperty is called. However, 2) works (i.e. 1 is returned) but neither getProperty nor invokeMethod is called.

Is there a way to intercept the getfoo() call as well?

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article a couple of months ago. You can read it [here](http://ssscripting.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/some-groovy-metamagic-in-practice/).

Try this code :

```
TestClass.metaClass.invokeMethod = {
   def metaMethod = delegate.metaClass.getMetaMethod(method,args)
   println "executing $method with args $args on $delegate"
   return metaMethod.invoke(delegate,args)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify the code in a previous answer a bit to get what I think you want:

```
TestClass.metaClass.invokeMethod = {method, args ->
  def metaMethod = TestClass.metaClass.getMetaMethod(method,args)
  println "executing $method with args $args on $delegate"
  metaMethod.invoke(delegate,args) // could result in NPE
}
```

Then executing

```
tc.foo
tc.getFoo()
```

Results in:

```
getting property: foo                               // println output
null                                                // getProperty return is null
executing getFoo with args [] on TestClass@655538e5 // invokeMethod output
1                                                   // metaMethod invocation
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are two different kinds of paths how a request is handled is used here. For asking properties the getProperty method is called before we go into the meta class - if you overwrite getProperty you have to do the meta class call yourself actually. In case of invokeMethod it is normally asked *after* the meta class has been asked. Since the meta class will respond to your asking for getFoo(), invokeMethod will not be asked at all. If you let the class implement GroovyInterceptable then invokeMethod is asked first, the same way as getProperty. That also explains why the ways using the meta class instead do work.